# Is there an Excel formula to compare two dates to see if they are >90 days apart and then repeat for dates after that?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I apologize for how I worded the title, but I am having a hard time really distilling my issue into a snappy soundbite.

My problem is this: Using the data below, for each User ID I need to find each instance that a date differs from a previous one by 90 or more days. BUT then, once 90 day difference is found, it needs to "reset" and look for dates 90 or more days from that.

Basically, I want a formula that can reproduce the Result column in the below table.

[image]

For example, note how for User ID 1 that the first 8/30 date yields a positive result, but neither the second 8/30 nor the 9/21 do, since they are both less than 90 days distant from 8/30. But then 12/26 does yield a positive result, since it is 118 days past the last positive result.

I really appreciate any help you can offer.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Example Image]

Eq#1: =DATEDIF(B3,C3,"D")

Eq#2: =IF(E3>90,"Do a little dance","Frowny Face")

Comment: You can definitely combine those two equations into a single longer equation, but I separated them just because I felt it looked a little more clean & understandable that way.